# querySelectorAll for any div within an element

Tags: javascript, html, queryselectall

I'd expect this to pop up an alert for any div I click inside the section id `playGrid`, but it does nothing.

```
<div id="playGrid" class="w">
  <section>
    <div id="0_0"></div>
    <div id="0_1"></div>
    <div id="0_2"></div>
    <div id="0_3"></div>

    <div id="1_0"></div>
    <div id="1_1"></div>
    <div id="1_2"></div>
    <div id="1_3"></div>

    <div id="2_0"></div>
    <div id="2_1"></div>
    <div id="2_2"></div>
    <div id="2_3"></div>

    <div id="3_0"></div>
    <div id="3_1"></div>
    <div id="3_2"></div>
    <div id="3_3"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("playGrid").querySelectorAll('section div').forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(this.id);
  });
});
```

Comment: as long as those divs aren't empty as show, it does work

Comment: The `<div>` elements are empty; they'll take up no space on the screen so how are you going to click on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your code runs before the document is fully loaded. To run your code after page is loaded add event listener for 'DOMContentLoaded' event:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  document.getElementById("playGrid").querySelectorAll('section div').forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert(this.id);
    });
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/mikhailsidorov/pen/BaoPKoX

Answer (score 0):

two options add content like so

```
  <section>
    <div id="0_0">content</div>
    <div id="0_1">content</div>
    <div id="0_2">content</div>
    <div id="0_3">content</div>

    <div id="1_0">content</div>
    <div id="1_1"></div>
    <div id="1_2"></div>
    <div id="1_3"></div>

    <div id="2_0"></div>
    <div id="2_1"></div>
    <div id="2_2"></div>
    <div id="2_3"></div>

    <div id="3_0"></div>
    <div id="3_1"></div>
    <div id="3_2"></div>
    <div id="3_3"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

or use css by adding a class `.content` to all your divs :

```css
.content{
height: 10px;
width:10px;
}
```

Comment: or `section>div { height: 10px }` - no width needed, no class needed

Comment: yes this will work unless you have other sections that have divs as direct children it will break

Comment: well, then `#playGrid>section>div` :p can't have more than one `#playGrid` :p

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Also, make sure your script is being executed after the page loads, not before. Use the `defer` tag on your `<script>` element or move the `<script>` element to the end of your body.

```js
[ ...document.querySelectorAll('#playGrid section div') ].forEach((div) => {
   div.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      alert(event.currentTarget.id);
   });
});
```